# moving element on top of another element on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two elements and a button. I'm trying to make the first element to be completely on top of the other element when the button is clicked.

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
   $("#frist_element").appendTo("#second_element")

})
```

```css
div{
 background-color: red;
 width: 30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}


#second_element{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first_element"></div>
<div id="second_element"></div>

<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
```

when the button is clicked the red circle should move(animate to move) to the yellow circle and the green circle should not be visible

Update:
here is a gif that shows exactly what im looking for [gif](https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-b58c3edefd.gif)

Comment: What do you mean on top of? Like the z-index should overlay one on the other, or you would just want to show the green circle where the red circle is?

Comment: just play with display none and block instead of on top?

Comment: when the button is cliked the red circle should move to the yellow circle and the yellow circle should not be visable

Comment: @halmos there is no yellow circle.

Comment: sorry green i ment

Comment: So, when they click the button again, what should happen?

Comment: the red div should move to the green div. as a result, the green div should not be visible

Comment: Typo `#frist_element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, I just add position relative to the first div and took the top position of the second and added to the first div using the [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) funtion . After that the first goes to on the second div.

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    var secondDivPosition=$("#second_element").position();
       var firstDivPosition=$("#first_element").position();
 
    var topSecond =secondDivPosition.top.toString()+'px';
      var topFirst =firstDivPosition.top.toString()+'px';
      
    if(firstDivPosition.top==secondDivPosition.top)
    {
      $("#first_element").animate({"top":"0px"},300, function() {});
            $("#second_element").css({"visibility":"initial"});
      
   
    }else
    {
      $("#first_element").animate({"top":topSecond},300, function() {
        $("#second_element").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
      });
    
      
    
    }

  
  });
```

```css
div{
 background-color: red;
 width: 30px;
 height:30px;
 margin: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

  #first_element{
    position: relative;
   }


#second_element{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first_element"></div>
<div id="second_element"></div>

<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: if you update your answer so that the the transition is in slow motion(nicer) I will upvote and mark as the right answer

Comment: is not ready, wait, but you can upvote.

Comment: Ready is already animate, if you want i could add less time on the animation

Comment: Now is more slowly, thanks

Comment: what up i fix it, is working as you wanted, no?

Comment: Ready, the green circle is not visible when the red is on top of it, is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the css [transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) might come handy for you. Also added a transition delay to look nicer. Is this what you were looking for?

```js
$("#clickme").click(function(){
   $("#second").css("transform","translateY(-50px)");
   $("#first").css("transform","translateY(50px)");
 });
```

```css
div{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
#first {
  background-color: red;
}
#second {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>

<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: If you update your answer so that when you click again the red moves over the green I will upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute with a flag and use the functions before and after.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    div{
        background-color: red;
        width: 30px;
        height:30px;
        margin: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    #second_element{
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#clickme").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
                $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
                $("#first_element").before($("#second_element"))
            } else {
                $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
                $("#first_element").after($("#second_element"))
            };
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="first_element"></div>
<div id="second_element"></div>

<button id="clickme">Click Me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `container` to detect which is the current `status`
then just `capture` the `divs` and then play with them

hope it helps

```js
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
      var first=  $("#first_element");
      var second=  $("#second_element");
    if(!$('.container').hasClass('red-green')){
      $('.container').addClass('red-green');    
       $("#first_element").remove();
       $("#second_element").after(first);
    }else {
       $('.container').removeClass('red-green');
       $("#second_element").remove();
       $("#first_element").after(second);
    }

    })
```

```css
 #first_element{
     background-color: red;
     width: 30px;
     height:30px;
     margin: 20px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: block;
    }


    #second_element{
    background-color: green;
    width: 30px;
     height:30px;
     margin: 20px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="first_element"></div>
    <div id="second_element"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="clickme">Click Me</button>
```